# Postgresl backup and bad id sequence values

Tags: postgresql

I received a bad backup script file (sql) which contains multiple sequences with bad current values.

The current values!= the last id of the row of the tables.

So the next insertion fails at runtime because id already exists (sequence value lower than the last values).

The file contains a lot a tables and a lot of sequences. So manually edit is fastidious.

Is it possible to refresh the sequence values with the last row ids with a script 
 or special command after restore of the bad backup file?